# Aliasing find method gives UnauthorizedAccess error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeresource

I am aliasing ActiveResource's find method with my own custom method so that I may add some attributes before I return data.

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base  
  class << self
    alias_method :find_original, :find

    def find(username='Guest')
      @user_info = find_original(username)
    end
  end
end
```

The above code works just fine 100% of the time. The problem occurs when I try to create a new instance of User in the find method.

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base  
  class << self
    alias_method :find_original, :find

    def find(username='Guest')
      @user_info = find_original(username)
      @user = new(username: username, user_settings: {})
    end
  end
end
```

edit:

This code only works for the first username I send it:

```
User.find('user1')
=> #<User:0x007fab51df5990 @attributes={"username"=>"user1", "user_settings"=>#     <User::UserSettings:0x007fab51dfe2e8 @attributes={}, @persisted=false, @prefix_options={}>}, @persisted=false, @prefix_options={}>
```

If I try to use any other usernames during the same session, I get this error:

```
 User.find('user2')
ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess: Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = [ISS.0084.9001] Invalid credentials. app/models/user.rb:21:in `find'
```

I have tried using super (instead of alias_method), and naming my find method something that wouldn't create any collisions (like `def find_blah`). Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your `find` method is setting some class instance variables. Also, how do you have your DB model set up so that `Guest` is a valid ID?

Comment: We are setting username on CAS login. 'Guest' is a valid username. I have edited my question with a bit more explanation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm super confused that it works at all. When your new `find` method calls `find_original`, it should attempt to find a record with ID `user1`. Unless you have set up your schema in an unusual way, or unless you have a user with ID=0, that call should raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Comment: Also, I'm like 99% sure you don't actually want to set the `@user` class instance variable. Even if you didn't hit the `ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess` error, you would still only have one `@user` for your entire `User` class.

Comment: My apologies, I failed to mention that we are using a strange API (with ActiveResource) where the username is actually the id. I will attempt removing the class instance variables to see that if allows me to do what it is I want.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Also, in your method, you aren't doing anything with the "found" user (apart from setting the `@user_info` variable. What do you want to do with that? I've added an answer for what I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comments, I'm not sure what you are trying to do. However, maybe you are trying to do this:

```
User.where(username: username).first_or_initialize
```

Or to wrap this in a method:

```
class User
  def self.custom_find(username='Guest')
    where(username: username).first_or_initialize
    # or where(id: username).first_or_initialize
  end
end
```